# How to get the infinitive form of the verb using "stanza"?

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech, stanza

How to find out the infinitive verbs in a sentence using stanza?

Example:

```
doc = "I need you to find the verbes in this sentence"
en_nlp = stanza.Pipeline('en', processors='tokenize,lemma,mwt,pos,depparse', verbose=False, use_gpu=False)
processed = en_nlp(doc)

print(*[f"id: {word.id}\t word: {word.text}\t POS: {word.pos}\t head id: {word.head}\t head: {sent.words[word.head-1].text if word.head > 0 else 'root'} \t deprel: {word.deprel}" for sent in processed.sentences for word in sent.words], sep='\n')
```

The output:

```
id: 1    word: I     POS: PRON   head id: 2  head: need      deprel: nsubj
id: 2    word: need  POS: VERB   head id: 0  head: root      deprel: root
id: 3    word: you   POS: PRON   head id: 2  head: need      deprel: obj
id: 4    word: to    POS: PART   head id: 5  head: find      deprel: mark
id: 5    word: find  POS: VERB   head id: 2  head: need      deprel: xcomp
id: 6    word: the   POS: DET    head id: 7  head: verbes    deprel: det
id: 7    word: verbes    POS: NOUN   head id: 5  head: find      deprel: obj
id: 8    word: in    POS: ADP    head id: 10     head: sentence      deprel: case
id: 9    word: this  POS: DET    head id: 10     head: sentence      deprel: det
id: 10   word: sentence  POS: NOUN   head id: 5  head: find      deprel: obl
```

However, in this line:

> id: 5  word: find  POS: VERB   head id: 2  head: need      deprel: xcomp

I need something to say that it is an infinitive verb.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question, wasn't keen on breaking into the tokenizer and ended up tweaking the stanza sentence.words.

The word.feats indicates the infintival verb form as in id 7 here, I haven't tested how reliably.

```
test_resp = "He was a little scared to knock on the door"
res = nlp(test_resp)
res.sentences[0].words[4:8]
```

gives this

```
[{
   "id": 5,
   "text": "scared",
   "lemma": "scared",
   "upos": "ADJ",
   "xpos": "JJ",
   "feats": "Degree=Pos",
   "head": 0,
   "deprel": "root",
   "misc": "start_char=16|end_char=22"
 },
 {
   "id": 6,
   "text": "to",
   "lemma": "to",
   "upos": "PART",
   "xpos": "TO",
   "head": 7,
   "deprel": "mark",
   "misc": "start_char=23|end_char=25"
 },
 {
   "id": 7,
   "text": "knock",
   "lemma": "knock",
   "upos": "VERB",
   "xpos": "VB",
   "feats": "VerbForm=Inf",
   "head": 5,
   "deprel": "advcl",
   "misc": "start_char=26|end_char=31"
 },
 {
   "id": 8,
   "text": "on",
   "lemma": "on",
   "upos": "ADP",
   "xpos": "IN",
   "head": 10,
   "deprel": "case",
   "misc": "start_char=32|end_char=34"
 }]
```

For my purposes it was more useful to treat the string "to verb" as a single lexical item and update the word.text as "to_verb" and the verb's character span to match. This leaves the verb's word.lemma and word.upos as VERB unchanged but requires decrementing the head and word position indexes of the verb and following words to account for deleting the "to".

The deepcopy protects the original example for illustration, better to avoid it if possible.

```
import re
import sys
from copy import deepcopy

def patch_inf_verb(processed):
    """hack the parse to treat 'to VERB' as one word"""
 
    # modified sentence
    results = deepcopy(processed)
    
    # regex to captures the text and numerals in  word.misc, 
    # e.g., 'start_char=11|stop_char=13'
    misc_vals_re = re.compile("(start_char=)(\d+)(\|end_char=)(?P<end>\d+)")

    for result in results.sentences:
        for wdx, word in enumerate(result.words):
            
            # peek back for "to"
            if wdx > 0 and word.pos == "VERB":
                one_back =  result.words[wdx - 1]
                if one_back.text.lower() == "to" and one_back.head == word.id:
                    
                    word.text = "to_" + word.text
                    # word.upos = "VERB_INF"  # update upos tag or leave as is

                    # parse verb's character span string
                    vals = misc_vals_re.match(word.misc).groups()
                    assert vals is not None
   
                    # nudge word.misc start_char back to span one-back "to"
                    word.misc = f"{vals[0]}{int(vals[1])-3}{vals[2]}{int(vals[3])}"
                    assert misc_vals_re.match(word.misc) is not None

                    # decrement the indexes for verb position and beyond,
                    # the character spans don't change
                    for tdx in range(len(result.words)):
                        if result.words[tdx].id > wdx: result.words[tdx].id -= 1
                        if result.words[tdx].head > wdx: result.words[tdx].head -= 1
                    
                    # clobber the "to" after
                    del result.words[wdx - 1]
    return results

def format_results(results):
    """results in table format"""
    results_str = '\n'.join(
        [
            "\t".join(
                    [
                        f"{key:5s}: {val}" 
                        for key, val in word.to_dict().items() 
                        if key not in ["lemma", "feats"]
                    ]
                )
                for sent in results.sentences 
                for word in sent.words
            ]
        )
    return results_str
```

OP example:

```
print("python", sys.version)
print("stanza version:", stanza.__version__)

doc = "I need you to find the verbes in this sentence"
en_nlp = stanza.Pipeline('en', processors='tokenize,lemma,mwt,pos,depparse', verbose=False, use_gpu=False)
processed = en_nlp(doc)

print('OP stanza before\n', format_results(processed))

patched_to_verb = patch_inf_verb(processed)
print("after patch_inf_verb\n", format_results(patched_to_verb))
```

---

```
python 3.7.7 (default, Mar 26 2020, 15:48:22) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
stanza version: 1.1.1
OP stanza before
 id   : 1   text : I    upos : PRON xpos : PRP  head : 2    deprel: nsubj   misc : start_char=0|end_char=1
id   : 2    text : need upos : VERB xpos : VBP  head : 0    deprel: root    misc : start_char=2|end_char=6
id   : 3    text : you  upos : PRON xpos : PRP  head : 2    deprel: obj misc : start_char=7|end_char=10
id   : 4    text : to   upos : PART xpos : TO   head : 5    deprel: mark    misc : start_char=11|end_char=13
id   : 5    text : find upos : VERB xpos : VB   head : 2    deprel: xcomp   misc : start_char=14|end_char=18
id   : 6    text : the  upos : DET  xpos : DT   head : 7    deprel: det misc : start_char=19|end_char=22
id   : 7    text : verbes   upos : NOUN xpos : NNS  head : 5    deprel: obj misc : start_char=23|end_char=29
id   : 8    text : in   upos : ADP  xpos : IN   head : 10   deprel: case    misc : start_char=30|end_char=32
id   : 9    text : this upos : DET  xpos : DT   head : 10   deprel: det misc : start_char=33|end_char=37
id   : 10   text : sentence upos : NOUN xpos : NN   head : 5    deprel: obl misc : start_char=38|end_char=46
after patch_inf_verb
 id   : 1   text : I    upos : PRON xpos : PRP  head : 2    deprel: nsubj   misc : start_char=0|end_char=1
id   : 2    text : need upos : VERB xpos : VBP  head : 0    deprel: root    misc : start_char=2|end_char=6
id   : 3    text : you  upos : PRON xpos : PRP  head : 2    deprel: obj misc : start_char=7|end_char=10
id   : 4    text : to_find  upos : VERB xpos : VB   head : 2    deprel: xcomp   misc : start_char=11|end_char=18
id   : 5    text : the  upos : DET  xpos : DT   head : 6    deprel: det misc : start_char=19|end_char=22
id   : 6    text : verbes   upos : NOUN xpos : NNS  head : 4    deprel: obj misc : start_char=23|end_char=29
id   : 7    text : in   upos : ADP  xpos : IN   head : 9    deprel: case    misc : start_char=30|end_char=32
id   : 8    text : this upos : DET  xpos : DT   head : 9    deprel: det misc : start_char=33|end_char=37
id   : 9    text : sentence upos : NOUN xpos : NN   head : 4    deprel: obl misc : start_char=38|end_char=46
```